# Styling selected LIstItemButton MUI not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

According to the documentation, I can override the style of the selected class by passing a new class under .MuiSelected. something like below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  selectedLink: {
    "&.Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  },
}));
```

Then, I use it:

```
const MainDrawerMenu: React.FC = () => {
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();
  // Responsive swipe on mobile
  const iOS =
    typeof navigator !== "undefined" &&
    /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);

  const handleSelected = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>,
    selectedIndex: number
  ) => {
    setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SwipeableDrawer
        classes={{ paper: classes.drawerMenuHolder }}
        disableBackdropTransition={!iOS}
        disableDiscovery={iOS}
        open={isDrawerOpen}
        onClose={() => {
          setIsDrawerOpen(false);
        }}
        onOpen={() => {
          setIsDrawerOpen(true);
        }}>
        <List disablePadding>
          <ListItemButton
            component={Link}
            classes={{ selected: classes.selectedLink }}
            to='/'
            onClick={(event) => {
              setIsDrawerOpen(false);
              handleSelected(event, 0);
            }}
            selected={selectedIndex === 0}>
            <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.drawerItem}>
              Home
            </ListItemText>
          </ListItemButton>
        </List>
      </SwipeableDrawer>
      <IconButton
        className={classes.iconMenuBtn}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen);
        }}>
        <MenuIcon fontSize='large' className={classes.menuIcon} />
      </IconButton>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Yet, it doesn't work. I can see it in the dev tools, but for some reason it gets overridden by another class. See screenshot. I have tried also creating a new class with the css naming convention but no luck...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution below:

```
<ListItemButton sx={{
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 0, 50, 0.1)'
        }
      }} selected={0}> 
     <ListItemText primary={'label in item selected'} />
</ListItemButton>
```